# How can I create a local highscore list in android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

May I know how do I create a high score list locally in the application (without going to any server or needed any internet connection).

Show the score you get after the game and when it's high score will ask you the name and will appear in the high score list?

Comment: Surely you can. Just use Sqlite for saving data locally.

Answer (score 1):

For simple stuff like this, you can implement using SharedPreferences.

Stack Overflow have extensive Q/A related to this:

- [how to store top high score in shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393968/how-to-store-top-high-score-in-shared-preference)
- [Show the highscore with shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747148/show-the-highscore-with-shared-preferences)
- [How to add and retrieve arraylist of value in shared preference in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283009/how-to-add-and-retrieve-arraylist-of-value-in-shared-preference-in-android)